# Actual type is `Maybe (Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)])` when I expect it to be `[(Nucleotide, Int)]`

Tags: haskell

I'm currently learning Haskell and am working on the Nucleotide Count problem on https://exercism.io/. The problem:

> Given a string representing a DNA sequence, count how many of each
> nucleotide is present. If the string contains characters that aren't
> A, C, G, or T then it is invalid and you should signal an error.

The compiler is giving me the following errors:

```
/Users/adamzerner/Exercism/haskell/nucleotide-count/src/DNA.hs:8:88: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Nucleotide, Int)]’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe (Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)])’
    • In the first argument of ‘Map.fromList’, namely ‘(Just result)’
      In the first argument of ‘Right’, namely
        ‘(Map.fromList (Just result))’
      In the expression: Right (Map.fromList (Just result))
  |
8 | nucleotideCounts xs = if result == Nothing then Left "Error" else Right (Map.fromList (Just result))
  |                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^

/Users/adamzerner/Exercism/haskell/nucleotide-count/src/DNA.hs:16:45: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[(Nucleotide, Int)]’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe (Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)])’
    • In the second argument of ‘updateAcc'’, namely ‘(Just acc)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘updateAcc' el (Just acc)’
      In the expression: Just $ updateAcc' el (Just acc)
   |
16 |   | isNucleotide el = Just $ updateAcc' el (Just acc)
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

For both, I'm expecting that it should be `[(Nucleotide, Int)]` instead of `Maybe (Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)])`. Here is my code:

```
module DNA (nucleotideCounts, Nucleotide(..)) where

import qualified Data.Map as Map

data Nucleotide = A | C | G | T deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

nucleotideCounts :: String -> Either String (Map.Map Nucleotide Int)
nucleotideCounts xs = if result == Nothing then Left "Error" else Right (Map.fromList (Just result))
  where
    result = Prelude.foldr updateAcc (Just acc) xs
    acc = [(A, 0), (C, 0), (G, 0), (T, 0)]

updateAcc :: Char -> Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)] -> Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)]
updateAcc _ Nothing = Nothing
updateAcc el acc
  | isNucleotide el = Just $ updateAcc' el (Just acc)
  | otherwise = Nothing

isNucleotide :: Char -> Bool
isNucleotide 'A' = True
isNucleotide 'C' = True
isNucleotide 'G' = True
isNucleotide 'T' = True
isNucleotide _ = False

updateAcc' :: Char -> [(Nucleotide, Int)] -> [(Nucleotide, Int)]
updateAcc' 'A' [(A, a), (C, c), (G, g), (T, t)] = [(A, (a + 1)), (C, c), (G, g), (T, t)]
updateAcc' 'C' [(A, a), (C, c), (G, g), (T, t)] = [(A, a), (C, (c + 1)), (G, g), (T, t)]
updateAcc' 'G' [(A, a), (C, c), (G, g), (T, t)] = [(A, a), (C, c), (G, (g + 1)), (T, t)]
updateAcc' 'T' [(A, a), (C, c), (G, g), (T, t)] = [(A, a), (C, c), (G, g), (T, (t + 1))]
```

For the first error, `result` comes from `updateAcc` basically. `updateAcc` returns `Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)]`. So by doing `Just` on that result, doesn't that deconstruct it into `[(Nucleotide, Int)]`? How does using `Just` introduce that second `Maybe` I'm seeing in the compiler's error message?

For the second error, my thought process is similar. `updateAcc` takes `acc` as it's second argument which is of type `Maybe [(Nucleotide, Int)]`. I need to deconstruct it for `updateAcc'`, so I used `Just`, and ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just got your wrapping and unwrapping swapped.

```
nucleotideCounts xs = case result of
  Nothing -> Left "Error"
  Just result -> Right (Map.fromList result)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^

             vvvvvvvvvv
updateAcc el (Just acc)
    | isNucleotide el = Just $ updateAcc' el acc
                                             ^^^
```

Applying the `Just` function adds a layer of `Maybe`; pattern-matching against a `Maybe` with a `Just` pattern removes a layer. All I've done here is move your two applications of the `Just` function into the corresponding pattern-matching position; this converts "adding a layer" to "removing a layer", for a net difference of two layers.